# write data to database with Nan in a integer column in database

Tags: python, csv, pandas, nan, vertica

As numpy.nan is a special float type in python,  I have a pandas.Dataframe, some columns are consists of integer and Nan. As we know these columns will be float datatype.   I want to copy pandas.Dataframe.to_csv , a CSV file,to database. But as those columns in CSV are float datatype (even I set 'object' type for them in pandas but they are converted to float when I do .to_csv), but the table schema of those columns in DB are the integer type, so they will be rejected to load in. this is the problem I got. what would be a good way to fix this? It's not good to change the DB schema.

for example I have a data = pandas.Dataframe() as below. ID: float Value: float

```
   ID       Value
0  1001.0    500.0 
1  1002.0    NaN
2  NaN       600.0
3  1003.0    800.0
```

How could I create a csv to be like this:

```
ID|Value
1001|500 
1002|
|600
1003|800
```

Comment: Format them as strings with zero decimals  `'{:0.0f}'.format(0.)`?

Comment: Hey Thanks.  Could you elaborate a little more?

Comment: Not without more data to play with.  Give me some sample data and I'll show you what I'm talking about.  You should read [**MCVE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [**HowToAsk**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry.I added a sample of data in the description.  let me know if it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.to_csv('yourfile.csv', sep='|', index=None, float_format='%0.0f')

ID|Value
1001|500
1002|
|600
1003|800
```